# Max Transmissionspeed ESP8266?

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, wifi, esp8266

i have an ESP and sending data to a C++ Terminalprogram to my PC.

I need a transmissionspeed of at least 100packets per second.

Right now I am only receiving 1000packets per 60s -> 16-17 Packets per second.

Network Setup ist a Socket connection: ESP-Server, Terminal-Client, Transmissionprotokoll->TCP/IP

TCP/IP is necessary! No UDP!

Nagle is already deactivated.

The Code right now is only for speedtesting so the while(runTransmission) never ends and will be fixed as soon as the speed is reached.

Used library is the ESP8266WiFi.h.

Code ESP:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Adafruit_BNO055.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>



/*SSID and Password for Connection*/
const char* ssid="ESP8266";
const char* password ="symphony";

IPAddress local_ip(192,168,11,1);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);

bool runTransmission;
bool stopTransmission;


WiFiServer server(1045);

Adafruit_BNO055 IMU = Adafruit_BNO055(-1, 0x28);



const unsigned long interval = 10;
//unsigned long previousmillis = 0;


//BNO055 data

double acc_x;
double acc_y;
double acc_z;

WiFiClient client; 

void readSensorData (){

  imu::Vector<3> acc = IMU.getVector(Adafruit_BNO055::VECTOR_ACCELEROMETER);
  acc_x = acc.x();
  acc_y = acc.y();
  acc_z = acc.z(); 
}


void setup() {


  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(local_ip,gateway,subnet);
  WiFi.softAP(ssid,password);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("IP Adresse: "); Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP()); 

  Serial.println("Wifi started");
  delay(100);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  //start BNO055
  IMU.begin();
  
  //Timer interrupt
  noInterrupts();
 
  //disabling Nagle
  client.setNoDelay(true);
  
}

void loop() {

  

 
 
  client = server.available();

  if(client){
    Serial.println("Client vorhanden");

    while(client.connected()){
     
      if(client.available()>0){
        
        Serial.println("Nachricht erhalten! Starten");

        runTransmission   = 1;
        stopTransmission  = 0;

      }else{
        stopTransmission  = 1;
        runTransmission   = 0;
      }

          //String c = client.readStringUntil(end);

        while(runTransmission){

         /*if(millis() - previousmillis  >= interval){
          Serial.println(millis()-previousmillis);           
          previousmillis += interval;}*/


          //interval for sending data
          delay(interval);

          //readSensorData();
          
          //represent a data size of 6 double values(48byte) in one TCP_Packet
          char msg[49] = "123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678";
          //client.println(msg);
          client.write((const char *) msg, 48);
             
          client.flush();

        }  

    }
  
 }
 
}
```

Code Terminal (C++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;


#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

void  main()
{
    string ipAddress = "192.168.11.1";
    int port = 1045;
    int counter = 0;
    bool runStatus = 1;
    bool listenStatus;

    //Initialize WinSock

    WSADATA data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    
   if (wsResult != 0) {
        
        cerr << "Cant start Winsock, ERR #" << wsResult << endl;
       return;

    }



    //Create socket

    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    
        cerr << "Cant create Socket2, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        return;
    }




    //structure

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);


    //connect server (ESP8266)
    int connResult = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {

        cerr << "Cant connect so server , Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }


    char buff[4096];


    string userInput;


  
    

   do {


        cout << " 1 zum starten der Uebertragung";
        getline(cin, userInput);


        //record starttime 
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        if (userInput.size() > 0) {
            int sendResult = send(sock, userInput.c_str(), userInput.size() + 1, 0);
            listenStatus = 1;

        

            //if (sendResult != SOCKET_ERROR)

            
           
            while(listenStatus = 1 && counter < 1000  )
            {   
        
                //wait for response 
                ZeroMemory(buff, 4096);
                int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buff, 4096, 0);
                if (bytesReceived > 0)
                {

                    cout << "Server: " << string(buff, 0, bytesReceived) << endl;
                    counter++;
                    cout << counter << endl;
                }

            }

        }

         auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = finish - start;
        std::cout << "Elapsed time for 1000 packets receiving with a data size 48bytes : " << elapsed.count() << " s\n";



   } while (runStatus && counter < 1000);
```

Output Terminal:
Elapsed time for 1000 packets receiving with a data size 48bytes : 61.7903 s

Wireshark:

[Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbQ0b.png)

Can someone help me how to increase Transmission speed ?

Rawsockets should be faster then Websockets or am I wrong ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're including the time it takes to output what you receive in the measurement. Console output on Windows is almost unbelievably slow.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes but wireshark outputs the same delay between 2 packets of delta_t = 40-50ms

Comment: Are you accounting for [Nagel's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)?

Comment: @Eljay i turned Nagel's algrithm off.

Answer (score 0):

the transmission speed is a direct function of the power received.
In other words if the signal received is not strong enough for a specific transmission rate, the device reduces the transmission speed to match the minimum power required for that speed.
I would suggest first of all to assess your received power, using WiFi.getNetworkInfo of the ESP8266WiFi.h library.
It is important to get the RSSI, or "Received Signal Strength Indicator," which is a measurement of how well your device can hear a signal from an access point or router.
To improve your received signal install an external antenna or a power amplifier.
Please let me know how it goes if you wish
All the best
Luca

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try it!